# Swapping view controllers between 2 on-screen nav controllers causes inconsistent hierarchy exception

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have a container view controller which handles 2 navigation controllers side-by-side. I need to sometimes move a bunch of view controllers from one nav stack onto the bottom of the other nav stack.

The problem is that I'm getting the `UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency` exception which is new in iOS 5. I'm not sure how to get around this. Using the push/pop methods works fine, however I need to insert things further down the stack so I'm accessing the view controller array itself. The code is:

```
- (void)swapViewController:(UIViewController *)controller {

    NSMutableArray *leftStack = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:_leftNavController.viewControllers];
    NSMutableArray *rightStack = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:_rightNavController.viewControllers];

    if ([leftStack containsObject:controller]) {

        // Left to right
        [leftStack removeObject:controller];
        [rightStack addObject:controller];
        [_leftNavController setViewControllers:leftStack];
        [_rightNavController setViewControllers:rightStack];

    } else {

        // Right to left
        [rightStack removeObject:controller];
        [leftStack addObject:controller];
        [_rightNavController setViewControllers:rightStack];
        [_leftNavController setViewControllers:leftStack];

    }

}
```

The full exception is:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'child view controller:<MyViewController: 0x6c4e7f0> should have parent view controller:<UINavigationController: 0x6a5d100> but requested parent is:<UINavigationController: 0x6a58c10>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a [response from the developer forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/584914#584914):

> When you grab the UINavigationController's view controllers and insert them into the other nav controller, they are still logically in the first navigation controller, hence the exception.
>
> Why not just create new view controller to do this with? If necessary you can have them share data or state, or even implement a full copy for them to make this more straightforward, but the inconsistency is directly coming from trying to have a view controller in two different controllers at the same time.

So I'll dispose of the original navigation controllers and re-create them for each VC transition.